# Xamarin.Forms ListView only updates once when SignalR method is called and not again after

Tags: xamarin.forms, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

So i have a XamarinForms app which pulls data via an api, and uses SignalR as a bridge between.

The problem i'm having is, I have a listview in my xaml file as seen here:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid Margin="20,0,20,0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout  Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView x:Name="MessageListView"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row ="0">
                <Entry Placeholder="Type a message" FontSize="16" x:Name="MessageEntry" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Now I have a signalR function that sends a message and then populates the listview via a blank list i have created for the occasion, and this does what it says on the tin but only after the first attempt.

So to be clear, it sends the message, and updates the listview, but ONLY once, if you run the function again, it sends the message in the database, but it doesnt update the listview.

here is my code:

public partial class MessageForm : ContentPage
{
private HubConnection hubConnection;

```
    public Command SendMessageCommand { get; }
    public Command ConnectCommand { get; }
    public Command DisconnectCommand { get; }

    List<MessageViewModel> MessageList = new List<MessageViewModel>();

    List<string> MessageViewListPayLoad = new List<string>();

    public MessageForm(string name, object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = name;
        MessageEntry.Completed += StartMessage;
        SendMessageCommand = new Command(async () => { await SendMessage(sender, e); });
        ConnectCommand = new Command(async () => await Connect());
        DisconnectCommand = new Command(async () => await Disconnect());

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl($"http://myapiID/chatHub")
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", message =>
        {
            
        });

        hubConnection.On<List<MessageViewModel>>("ReceiveConversation", conversations =>
        {
            foreach(var message in conversations)
            {
                MessageViewListPayLoad.Add(message.MessageContent);
            }

            MessageListView.ItemsSource = MessageViewListPayLoad;
            
        });


    }


    async Task Connect()
    {
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

    }


    async Task Disconnect()
    {
        await hubConnection.StopAsync();

    }


    public async Task SendMessage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        await Connect(); 

        var model = new MessageViewModel
        {
            MessageContent = MessageEntry.Text,
            Receiver = Title,
            Sender = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("currentUser")
        };

        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", model);

        await UpdateCurrentConvo(await SecureStorage.GetAsync("currentUser"), Title);

        await Disconnect();
    }

    public async Task UpdateCurrentConvo(string user1, string user2)
    {
        user1 = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("currentUser");

        user2 = Title;

        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("UpdateCurrentConvo", user1, user2);
    }

    async void StartMessage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await SendMessage(sender, e); 
    }

}
```

now im not sure if this is a xamarin issue, or a signalr issue. i think its maybe to do with how i'm populating the listview, but I can't be sure and I can't see exactly where I'm going wrong.

here is my hub Code just incase:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public ChatHub(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(Message message)
    {
        var newMessage = new Message
        {
            MessageContent = message.MessageContent,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            Sender = message.Sender,
            Receiver = message.Receiver

        };

        _dbContext.Messages.Add(newMessage);

        var user = _dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Messages).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == message.Sender);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user.Messages.Add(newMessage);


            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }



    public async Task UpdateCurrentConvo(string user1, string user2)
    {
        var conversations = _dbContext.Messages.Where(x =>
                                 (x.Receiver == user1 || x.Receiver == user2) &&
                                 (x.Sender == user2 || x.Sender == user1)).ToList();

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveConversation", conversations);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use Essentials MainThread to be sure you are updating ItemsSource on the main UI thread

Comment: Hi there Jason! I wrapped my code like so: 

            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                hubConnection.On<List<MessageViewModel>>("ReceiveConversation", conversations =>
                {
                    foreach (var message in conversations)
                    {
                        MessageViewListPayLoad.Add(message.MessageContent);
                    }

                    MessageListView.ItemsSource = MessageViewListPayLoad;

                });
            });

but no joy :/

Comment: you should only need to wrap the one line that assigns ItemSource.  Have you verified that you are actually receiving messages and data?

Comment: Hi Jason, I am indeed receiving messages and data as the list gets populated the first time i run the function, it just doesnt do it the second time, however it is in the database. The UI just doesnt change as it does in the first instance.

it will appear in the list if i 'refresh' the page or go to another page and come back to it.

Comment: just because it receives it once doesn't mean that it gets subsequent updates.  Are you really sure it is working?  Have you verified with the debugger, or just by adding a Console.Writeline() into ReceiveConversation?  My other suggestion would be to change  MessageViewListPayLoad to an ObservableCollection and remove the line that updates ItemsSource ever time.

Comment: Hi Jason, I have looked at it with the debugger and it is 100% pulling in message data on the second attempt, it even writes it to the database as it should do, it just wont update the UI for some bizarre reason

Comment: the db update is on the server - how is that evidence that the client is receiving the message?

Comment: ahh apologies I misunderstood your point.  So do you mean this? 

            hubConnection.On<List<MessageViewModel>>("ReceiveConversation", conversations =>
            {

                foreach (var message in conversations)
                {
                    MessageViewListPayLoad.Add(message.MessageContent);
                }

                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    MessageListView.ItemsSource = MessageViewListPayLoad;
                });

            });

Comment: yes.  You need to verify that you are actually receiving the messages after the first is sent

Comment: hello sorry moment of stupidity there ahaha

so its looking like it reaches that part of the code as the message from the second attempt as it updates the MessageViewListPayLoad, it his the client as its in the list. it just wont print on the UI

Comment: did you follow my earlier suggestion about using ObservableCollection?

Comment: No i'll try that now, although I am unfamiliar with that so bear with me :)

Comment: Hi @Jason i dont think i've got this right,  but here 

 private ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> MessageViewListPayLoad;

            hubConnection.On<List<MessageViewModel>>("ReceiveConversation", conversations =>
            {

                foreach (var message in conversations)
                {
                    MessageViewListPayLoad.Add(message);
                }

                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    MessageListView.ItemsSource = MessageViewListPayLoad;
                });

            });

Comment: you only need to set the ItemsSource ONCE

Comment: Jason you are a gentleman and a scholar, thank you so much it worked beautifully!